# Javascript assign a function to a row onclick

Tags: javascript, vbscript

```
 Set oNewRow = ProgramTable.insertRow(-1)
 oNewRow.onClick = GetRef("HighLight")
```

ProgramTable is a Table ID and this function will add a row dynamically.

In the second line, "HighLight" function get assign to the newly added row onclick. (without executing the HighLight function at this step)

I want to do a similar task in Javascript.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

```
// oNewRow is the refrence to the newly added row
var oNewRow = ProgramTable.insertRow();

// assign the onclick function to the newly added row
oNewRow.onclick = function(){ GetRef("Highlight") };
```

i'm considering you know the logic which goes inside the insert row and GetRef function. The above code only explains how to add an onclick function to a row.

Comment: Thank you..
But the function name to be assign is HighLight()...
GetRef is a key word in VBScript.
Can you please help me with that....

Comment: you can directly mention, Highlight then.
oNewRow.onclick = function{ Highlight() };

if you need the row to be present in the function pass this as a parameter to the function.